# python3 tkinter falha na atribuição dos butões

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

boa tarde,
Eu estou tentando desenvolver uma interface grafica com o python e para isso estou a utilizar o tkinter porem esta a surgir um problema, sempre que eu tento atribuir uma função a um botão das duas uma ou o programa da erro e não corre ou simplesmente executa a função do botão sem eu carregar nele e mesmo que eu carregue no botão o comando não executa o meu código é o seguinte:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

try:
    from tkinter import *
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    os.system('pip3 install tkinter') #instala o modulo caso ele não esteja instalado por algum razão
inftext=['Verdana','12']


class primeirajanela:
    def login(self):
        print('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
    def __init__(self,master=None): #Master = janela
        #criação e posicionamento dos conteiners
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        frame2=Frame(master)
        frame2.pack()

        self.login=Button(frame,text='login',comand=self.login())
        self.login.pack()
#Criaçao e configuração básica da janela
janela = Tk()
janela.title('PAP')
janela.resizable(width=True,height=True)
janela.geometry('800x600+100+50') #alturax largura + distanciaEsquerda +Margemtopo
#Passa os dados da janela em argumento para a classe
primeirajanela(janela)
janela.mainloop()
```

isto  suposto ser um teste e ele apenas imprimir aquilo eu sei q neste caso poderia facilmente utilizar o `lambda`mas vai ser para ter comandos mais complexos o que tornaria inviável utilizar o lambda

P.S: caso eu tire os parêntesis nesta parte do código `comand=self.login` o programa simplesmente da erro e não corre

se alguem poder ajudar agredeço :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variável que você ta usando pra criar um botão tem o mesmo nome da função.
O parâmetro do Button é "command".

```
button = Button(frame,text='login',command=self.login)
button.pack()
```